# Is IF statement allow OR condition in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

how to test if my condition is this;

```
<xsl:if test="node = '1' or node='2'">
<input name="list_{@id}" value="{@id}" type="checkbox"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Is IF statement allowed OR condition? Please advice..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is IF statement allowed OR condition?

No, but XPath has an `or` operator -- do note that XPath is case-sensitive language.

**The XPath expression in the provided code**:

```
node = '1' or node='2'
```

**is syntactically correct**.

**`or` is a [standard XPath operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-Operator) and can be used to combine two subexpressions**.

> [33]    OperatorName    ::=    'and' | 'or' | 'mod' | 'div'

Here is a complete XSLT transformation example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num[ . = 3 or . = 5]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced (all elements copied with the exception of `<num>03</num>` and `<num>05</num>`:**

```
<nums>
   <num>01</num>
   <num>02</num>
   <num>04</num>
   <num>06</num>
   <num>07</num>
   <num>08</num>
   <num>09</num>
   <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use or just like you did in your example. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp) are the supported operators in XSLT.

Comment: Oleksi: The operators of the XPath language are in the respective W3C specification -- this is the only *normative* document for XPath. **Posting a reference to w3schools is improper and actually a bad advice to the OP**. Read more about the trustworthiness of w3schools at: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: The link does 404 now.